# Question about LINQ2Sql performance in C#

Tags: c#, performance, linq-to-sql

From a performance perspective, is it better to wrap each statement that utilizes LINQ in a using() statement, or to declare a class-level instance and use in each method?

For instance:

```
public void UpdateSomeRecord(Record recordToUpdate)
{
    using(var entities = new RecordDBEntities())
    {
        // logic here...
    }
}


private RecordDBEntities entites = new RecordDBEntities();
public void UpdateSomeRecord(Record recordToUpdate)
{
    // logic here...
}
```

Or does it not matter either way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `using` statement may hurt performance in the sense that it will take longer to run but this shouldn't be your concern in cases like this.  If a type implements `IDisposable` it really ought to be wrapped in a `using` statement so that it can clean up after itself.

This cleanup code will take longer to run than no cleanup code of course so that is why I say that the `using` statement will take longer to run.  But this does not mean that you *shouldn't* have the `using` statement.  I think that you *should* use the `using` statement even though it may take longer to run.

I guess what I am trying to say is that you are comparing apples to oranges here as performance comparisons only make sense when the code being compared creates identical output and identical side effects.  Your examples do not so that I why I don't think this is a performance issue.

The best practice in this situation is to use the `using` statement on types that implement `IDisposable` regardless of the fact that the `using` statement will make the method run longer.  If you need to know *how* much longer it will run then you should employ a profiler to identify if the code in question is creating a bottleneck.

Comment: OK that sort of makes sense. The code I posted is from an Interface I am building, but it does not implement the dispose method. I suppose I could add it and call it in the main section, but from what you are saying it would be better in the long run to wrap each segment in its own Using statement to take care of the disposing, correct?

Comment: I imagine my question was poorly formed. Maybe best practices instead: What is the best practice for LINQ queries in C#?

Comment: Don't *add* an implementation of `IDisposable` if one does not already exist and is not needed.  If you don't need to dispose of any unmanaged resources then your don't need the interface! :)

For more info please read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx.

Answer (score 2):

In fact your question is about the lifetime management of the LINQ DataContext.

You may wish to look at the following article: [Linq to SQL DataContext Lifetime Management](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/246222.aspx)